# Django Apache mod_wsgi - Unable to open database file

Tags: python, django, apache, sqlite, mod-wsgi

After upgrading mod_wsgi to the latest version, my app can no longer access its caching db (sqlite).

The Apache error log shows the following:

```
mod_wsgi (pid=1050): Target WSGI script '/location/to_my_project/project_name/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
mod_wsgi (pid=1050): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/location/to_my_project/project_name/wsgi.py'.
aceback (most recent call last):
File "/location/to_my_project/project_name/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
  application = get_wsgi_application()
File "/location/to/my/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
  return WSGIHandler()
File "/location/to/my/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 153, in __init__
  self.load_middleware()
File "/location/to/my/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 80, in load_middleware
  middleware = import_string(middleware_path)
File "/location/to/my/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 20, in import_string
  module = import_module(module_path)
File "/location/to/my/env/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/location/to_my_project/project_name/middleware/some_middleware.py", line 16, in <module>
  include_get_headers=True,
File "/location/to/my/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests_cache/core.py", line 182, in install_cache
  backend = backends.create_backend(backend, cache_name, backend_options)
File "/location/to/my/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests_cache/backends/__init__.py", line 50, in create_backend
  return registry[backend_name](cache_name, **options)
File "/location/to/my/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests_cache/backends/sqlite.py", line 28, in __init__
  self.responses = DbPickleDict(location + extension, 'responses', fast_save=fast_save)
File "/location/to/my/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests_cache/backends/storage/dbdict.py", line 58, in __init__
  with self.connection() as con:
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
  return next(self.gen)
File "/location/to/my/env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests_cache/backends/storage/dbdict.py", line 70, in connection
  con = sqlite.connect(self.filename)
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

The user running the process, has however created the file after the error has occurred. When logging in with that user, I can also open / edit the file. Other users with the same problem have reported that changing the path to the file from absolute to relative have solved their issue, but mine has been relative all along. the cache is also created in the correct directory.

- mod_wsgi version: 4.5.14 (previous version 4.3.0)
- Django: 1.10
- Apache: 2.4.18
- Server: Ubuntu 16.04

I have not changed the python path after upgrading the wsgi module. Any suggestions on what might be wrong?

Comment: Btw, when I deactivate the cache, the server runs normally.

Comment: I would start to debug by adding `print(self.filename)` above this line: https://github.com/reclosedev/requests-cache/blob/master/requests_cache/backends/storage/dbdict.py#L70

Comment: Apache usually runs your code as a special user and not one which has write access to directories and files. You either need to give access to the Apache user write access to directory database file is in, as well as the database file. Alternatively, ensure using mod_wsgi daemon mode and set up mod_wsgi to run your WSGI application as the user who owns the database directory.

Comment: @dahrens: I've done that, and it prints the name of the file (not the entire path). Isn't that correct?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I've tried given `chmod 777` on the file without any luck. Doesn't Apache by standard run as www-data? When i log in with that user, I am able to edit/create/delete files in that directory. As mentioned in my initial post, the cache file actually gets created by the apache user. So it is able to create the file, just not read from it.

Comment: Have you changed directory permissions for database directory as well as indicated. Making the file writable is not enough.

Comment: Wow, that really didn't cross my mind. When making the file executable, the server started working again. I'm still unsure why the apache user is able to create a file it cannot execute, but thats a unix question, and something I can read up on on my own. Thank you for you help @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: The problem is that SQLite needs to create a database lock file or something in the same directory, thus it also needs to be able to write to the directory.